# Scala version issue using play-swagger-service template

Tags: playframework, swagger-2.0

I am new to Play Framework. I am implementing REST APIs and want to have Swagger Ui installed. My activator version is typesafe-activator-1.3.10.

I created my project with play-swagger-service template and it has issue to start up:

```
[info] Done updating.
[warn] Scala version was updated by one of library dependencies:
[warn]  * org.scala-lang:scala-library:(2.11.7, 2.11.0, 2.11.6) -> 2.11.8
[warn] To force scalaVersion, add the following:
[warn]  ivyScala := ivyScala.value map { _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true) }
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.11:2.6.1 -> 2.7.4
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
```

I set scalaVersion := "2.11.8" in build.sbt and I was getting more errors.

How could the dependencies issue be resolved?

I am using Java, does that make any difference?

Thank you!

Comment: it seems to be related to this github issue: https://github.com/zalando/api-first-hand/issues/33 and the fact that the jackson module was updated

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That case is still open and they are redesigning the whole generated code. Is there a solution besides waiting for their fix? Thank you!

Comment: I found another plugin at https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger which works fine but provides only simple documentation.